# Understanding this Python decorator code

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have problem in understanding this code that I got from book "Learning Python" section decorators.

Why this code return result's variable value once instead of twice? We returned the amount of result variable twice, once in "max_result" and another in "measure"; here is the code:

```
from time import sleep, time
from functools import wraps

def measure(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t = time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(func.__name__, 'took:', time() - t)
        return result
    return wrapper

def max_result(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if result > 100:
            print('Result is too big ({0}). Max allowed is 100.'
                  .format(result))
        return result
    return wrapper

@measure
@max_result
def cube(n):
    return n ** 3

print(cube(2))
print(cube(5))
```

Here is the output, why don't we get two 8 or two 125?

```
>>> print(cube(2))
cube took: 8.106231689453125e-06
8
>>> print(cube(5))
Result is too big (125). Max allowed is 100.
cube took: 5.91278076171875e-05
125
>>>
```

Comment: Why do you think that you should get two 8?

Comment: There are only three print statements involved and each gets executed at most once.

Comment: the boock says:
 "On the second call, the result is 125 , so the error message is printed, the result
returned, and then it's the turn of measure , which prints the running time again,
and finally, we print the result ( 125 )."
 so we returne result two times what happen to one of them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decorators are *chained*. The original `cube()` function was wrapped by the `max_result` decorator, and the *result* of that decoration was decorated by `measure`.

So the return value of `cube()` is taken by `wrapper()` in `max_result()`, and the result of that function is taken by `wrapper()` in `measure()` before being returned to the caller.

Unraveling all the decorators would give you:

```
def measure_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    t = time()
    result = max_result_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    print(func.__name__, 'took:', time() - t)
    return result

def max_result_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    result = original_cube(*args, **kwargs)
    if result > 100:
        print('Result is too big ({0}). Max allowed is 100.'
              .format(result))
    return result

def original_cube(n):
    return n ** 3

cube = measure_wrapper
```

So calling `cube(2)` produces:

- `measure_wrapper(2)`, records `t = time()` and calls

  - `max_result_wrapper(2)`, which directly calls

    - `original_cube(2)`, which
    - returns `2 ** 3` is `8`
  - tests `8 > 100`, whichis false so
  - returns `8`
- prints the time the `max_result_wrapper()` call took and
- returns `8`

Comment: thanks for the answer , i understand it now completely .